# Different test behavior in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

I have task - write test for the page https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator

In the Chrome test work without problem. In the Firefox I get Exception NoSuchFrame.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.switchTo().frame("myFrame");
Webelement numberOfInstances = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
numberOfInstances.sendKeys("4");
```

After I correct code on that

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
       .until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("myFrame"));
Webelement numberOfInstances = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
       .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
numberOfInstances.sendKeys("4");
```

And now I get other exception: TypeError: can't access dead object

**UPD:**
May be, it will be helpful for anybody. This bug is typical for Firefox and here is no unique solution. It's problem appears when you try switch into frame. One of decision may be run recursive method or just Thread.sleep

```
public static void getToSomeFrame(WebDriver driver, String nameFrame) {
    try {
        if (countOfSwitchingInFrame < 10) {
            driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
            driver.switchTo().frame(0);
            new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
                    .until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(nameFrame));
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        countOfSwitchingInFrame++;
        getToSomeFrame(driver, nameFrame);
    }
```

where `countOfSwitchingInFrame`  - count of trying switch into frame.